# How to skip an iteration that is returning error message

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop, continue, yfinance

Below is code to get stock options data based on the stock's specific ticker symbol from a list (ticker). It is also based on the stock option's expiration date. But I am getting this error: "ValueError: Expiration `2021-07-30` cannot be found. Available expiration are: [2022-01-21, 2023-01-20]". I believe that is because certain stock's do not have options that expire on 2021-07-30, but somehow got in my list. How would I incorporate a continue statement to skip the option ticker if it does not have the available expiration date: 2021-07-30?

```
opt_df = DataFrame()

for symbol in tickers:
    ticker = yf.Ticker(symbol)
    opt = ticker.option_chain('2021-07-30')
    opt_df.append(opt)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try/except statement with ValueError exception?

```
opt_df = DataFrame()

for symbol in tickers:
    try:
        ticker = yf.Ticker(symbol)
        opt = ticker.option_chain('2021-07-30')
        opt_df.append(opt)
    except ValueError:
        continue
```